# change yTicklabel in matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to draw a plot that displays y tick labels are similar to the below image. How can I do that?
[image]

thanks for your attentions

Comment: The `ylabel` is "Error". What do you mean?

Comment: Oh, now I see what you mean. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
labels = [' 1 ';'10 '; '100'];
set(gca,'YTickLabel',lbls);
```

This will set the YtickLabels to 1, 10 and 100. If you want LaTeX to interpret your ticklabels such that you will see (10⁰,10¹,10²), you can download this file from matlab exchange. 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986

Answer (score 2):

The y axis is setup as logarithmic.

you can create plots similar to this using

```
semilogy(xData,yData)
```

If you wanted the plot to look the same, you would of course need to use the semilogy to plot the data and then also add x and y axis labels using something like the following

```
xlabel('Fitness Evaluations');
ylabel('Error');
```

If you truly want to only show the powers of 10 on the y axis, meaning the power number, you can do something like as follows

```
labels = sort(str2num(get(gca,'YTickLabel')));
set(gca,'YTickLabel',labels);
```

Comment: How can i modify the yTickLable of the plot? I want just show power of 10 in the y-axis